# Missing Glyph with fontspec, XeTeX and LyX

Tags: xetex, lyx, fontspec, windows

I'm getting the error for missing glyphs in LyX using XeTeX with fontspec on Windows. The error is `Missing character: There is no ^^C in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!`

The wierf thing is that the font LM Roman 10 actually supports the Lambda Character (https://fonts2u.com/lmroman10-regular.font).

Please Help!

The WME in TeX is:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\Lambda}$
\end{document}
```

The WME in LyX is just adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` to the preamble, and writing `$\mathrm{\Lambda}$` in the body of the document.

**EDIT:** Also happens without `fontenc`:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\Lambda}$
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2:** Verified that it happend also on Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use arbitrary symbols inside \mathrm. Why don't you use simply `\Lambda`?

Comment: First of all, with pdflatex it works, but unfortunately I have to use XeTeX. I don't want to just use \Lambda, because it's generated from the .bib file.

Comment: well \mathrm{\Lambda} is wrong code. That it works with pdflatex is more or less by chance. So you better correct whatever is generating this.

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xetex, you disable all its Unicode support and force incorrect hyphenation for anything except unaccented English.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the compiler to just use `\Lambda` whenever he looks for `\mathrm{\Lambda}`?

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{\Lambda}$

\end{document}
```

And also

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{\Lambda}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of loading `fontspec` with the `no-math` option, you could instead load `unicode-math` to set up your math alphabets with Unicode.  You could also use `mathastext` to set up your Greek letters or, in XeLaTeX, `mathspec`, or for a legacy NFSS font, `isomath`.

You can also copy-and-paste a Λ into your UTF-8 source.

The reason you’re getting the message about missing character 003, or `^C`, is that that’s the character slot for Λ in the legacy [OML encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OML_encoding), but in a Unicode font, 0x03 is a control character, control-C.